# Redirect sys.stdout from ping results to a wx.TextCtrl widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm trying to redirect the sys.stdout stream to a wx.TextCtrl widget. In this code, i used ping but how to redirect results to wx.textctrl or statictext widgets. I can send variable from my input to wx.statictext but not able to get the stdout from ping results. hope someone here can help.

I'm using python 3.6.0 with wx 2.8.12.1

```
import wx
import os


class RandomPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, color):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour(color)



class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        topSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        vSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(topSplitter)

        panelOne = RandomPanel(vSplitter, "white")


        self.txt = wx.TextCtrl(panelOne, 
                    style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, 
                    pos=(7, 8), size=(330, 30))
        self.txt.SetFocus()
        self.txt.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.ping)

        panelTwo = RandomPanel(vSplitter, "white")
        vSplitter.SplitVertically(panelOne, panelTwo)
        vSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        panelThree = RandomPanel(topSplitter, "black")
        topSplitter.SplitHorizontally(vSplitter, panelThree)
        topSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)
        self.term = wx.StaticText(panelThree, -1, '', pos=(6, 100))
        self.term.SetForegroundColour((255, 255, 255))  #set font color
        self.term.SetBackgroundColour((0, 0, 0)) #set background color

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(topSplitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def ping(self, event):
        put = self.txt.GetValue()
        self.p = os.system("ping -n 1 "+put)
        self.term.SetLabel(put)
        self.p.AppendText('>>> ')
        self.p.AppendText(event)



class MainFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
           wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="ping tool",
                          size=(800, 600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `import os` with `from subprocess import call, Popen, PIPE, STDOUT`
Then replace

```
self.p = os.system("ping -n 1 "+put)
self.term.SetLabel(put)
self.p.AppendText('>>> ')
self.p.AppendText(event)
```

with

```
comm = Popen(['ping',put],stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT,universal_newlines=True)
for i in iter(comm.stdout.readline, b''):
    if i != '': pass
    else: break
    self.term.SetLabel(str(i))
    wx.Yield()
```

This will read the output from the ping command, output it and then call `Yield` to allow the wx.App() mainloop to update the screen from within the `for` loop

You will probably want to put a stop mechanism in there at some point.

Edit:
To create a set of rolling results, I would change `self.term` from a `StaticText` to a `TextCtrl`

```
self.term = wx.TextCtrl(panelThree, -1, '',size=(400,200),style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
```

and then in the `ping` routine change `SetLabel` to `AppendText`

```
def ping(self, event):
    put = self.txt.GetValue()
    comm = Popen(['ping',put],stdout=PIPE,stderr=STDOUT,universal_newlines=True)
    for i in iter(comm.stdout.readline, b''):
        if i != '': pass
        else: break
        self.term.AppendText(str(i))
        wx.Yield()
```

Comment: thankyou @Rolf of Saxon, 
it actually working, can i store all the results in an array then print out all?

Comment: thats what iam looking for.

Answer (score 0):

@Rolf of Saxony, i have updated the code thanks for your help.

```
def ping(self, event):
        a = []
        put = self.txt.GetValue()
        comm = Popen(['ping', put], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)
        for i in iter(comm.stdout.readline, b''):
            if i != '':
                pass
            else:
                break
            a.append(str(i))
            self.term.SetLabelText("start pinging......")
        self.term.SetLabelText("\n".join(a))
        wx.Yield()
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.